# C# Calling a Method on an Unknown Generic Type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a base class "ManagerBase" that has a generic static function "GetManager. There are two classes that inherit from ManagerBase ("ManagerSomething1" and "ManagerSomething2"). Each class has a static function "GetManager" which returns the inherited type of ManagerBase. How would I call GetManager without knowing the type?

```
public class ManagerBase
{
    public static T GetManager<T>(int managerID, bool withUsers, System.Func<SqlDataReader, T> del) where T : ManagerBase
    {
        T manager = del(dr);
        return manager;
    }
}

public class ManagerSomething1 : ManagerBase
{
    public static ManagerSomething1 GetManager<ManagerSomething1>(int managerID, bool withUsers)
    {
        return ManagerBase.GetManager<ManagerSomething1>(managerID, withUsers, dr => new ManagerSomething1(dr));
    }
}

public class ManagerSomething2 : ManagerBase
{
    public static ManagerSomething2 GetManager<ManagerSomething2>(int managerID, bool withUsers)
    {
        return ManagerBase.GetManager<ManagerSomething2>(managerID, withUsers, dr => new ManagerSomething2(dr));
    }
}

public static class SessionSharedHelper<T> where T : ManagerBase
{
    public static void InitializeSession(int managerID, bool withUsers)
    {
        SessionShared<T>.Manager = //I don't know how I can call ManagerBase.GetManager<T>(managerID, withUsers, ...);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure, but I have this nagging feeling you're trying to use generics where basic polymorphism would do the trick.

Comment: Can you explain the logic that will decide which of the two manager you should get?

Comment: There's no real logic; the type T defined in SessionSharedHelper is the same type that needs to get returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could refactor to something like this:

```
    public abstract class ManagerBase
    {
        public ManagerBase() { }

        public abstract void Initialize(int managerID, bool withUsers);
    }

    public class ManagerSomething1 : ManagerBase
    {
        public ManagerSomething1() 
        { }

        public override void Initialize(int managerID, bool withUsers)
        {
        }
    }

    public class ManagerSomething2 : ManagerBase
    {
        public ManagerSomething2()
        {
        }

        public override void Initialize(int managerID, bool withUsers)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public static class SessionSharedHelper<T> where T : ManagerBase, new()
    {
        public static void InitializeSession(int managerID, bool withUsers)
        {
            T manager = new T();
            manager.Initialize(managerID, withUsers);
        }
    }
```

Comment: beat me to it. You could also have each class provide a static method that gives you "del", if the OP is insistent on that.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work for me since the InitializeSession function is just supposed to retrieve the Manager and stick it into the session. The GetManager function needs to return an object of type ManagerBase.

Comment: Well in InitializeSession, T is an object inheriting from ManagerBase. So yes it is a ManagerBase.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work:

```
MethodInfo method_info = typeof(T).GetMethod("GetManager",
   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
SessionShared<T>.Manager = 
   (T)method_info.Invoke(null, new object[]{managerID, withUsers, ...});
```

Comment: You still ought to give some thought to refactoring. That's some serious code smell. :)

Comment: Using late binding to populate objects from the database? If this isn't a toy app, I don't recommend it.

Comment: I agree, inserting this code into the InitializeSession is not the optimal approach, I am looking into the other suggested solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to implement a factory pattern of some sort, inside of the classes you're trying to construct.

There are two ways you could go: Have a separate class that knows how to construct Manager1 and Manager2, or have the base class know how to construct each of its children. Either way, something needs to have knowledge of each of the subclasses. I don't think there's a good way to do what you have without reflection.

I'd probably implement something like this in a separate factory class.

```
public static T GetManager<T>(int managerID, bool withUsers) where T : ManagerBase
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Manager1))
    {
        return new Manager1(managerID, withUsers) as T;
    }
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Manager2))
    {
        return new Manager2(managerID, withUsers) as T;
    }

    throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought and I started writing that if statement inside the InitializeSession function and the compiler told me that neither condition could ever be met. Sure enough in debugging neither condition is met. It's very possible I was missing something though.

Comment: That's what I get for writing code in the browser instead of Visual Studio. Corrected cast vs. 'as', the proper name of the exception, and the number of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Something somewhere has to know/decide which type of Manager class to create when you say "give me the Manager* object for managerID x."  So one question that needs to be answered is how that decision is made.  Is that determined by some kind of data that comes back with the data reader?

Rather than having "GetManager" static methods, you could create a manager Factory or Repository class that understands how to determine which type of Manager object to create given a data reader.

Below is an example implementation.  The idea is that at some point early on, such as when your application is starting, you create a ManagerRepository and then register a "create" delegate for each type of Manager class that you have.  Later, when you request a Manager object from the ManagerRepository it will decide which type of Manager class to return and will utilize the "create" delegate that you registered for that type.

```
public class ManagerBase
{
}

class ManagerRepository
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Func<SqlDataReader, ManagerBase>> _ManagerCreateDelegates;

    public ManagerRepository()
    {
        _ManagerCreateDelegates = new Dictionary<Type, Func<SqlDataReader, ManagerBase>>();
    }

    public void RegisterCreate<T>(Func<SqlDataReader, ManagerBase> create)
        where T : ManagerBase
    {
        _ManagerCreateDelegates[typeof(T)] = create;
    }

    public ManagerBase GetManager(int managerID, bool withUsers)
    {
        SqlDataReader reader;
        reader = null;// TODO: obtain a data reader from somewhere...

        Type typeOfManager = this.DetermineManagerType(reader);

        Func<SqlDataReader, ManagerBase> create;
        if (_ManagerCreateDelegates.TryGetValue(typeOfManager, out create))
        {
            return create(reader);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("No create delegate has been registered for type [{0}].", typeOfManager.FullName));
        }
    }

    private Type DetermineManagerType(SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        // TODO: implement logic that uses the data reader to decide which type of Manager object to create
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ManagerSomething1 : ManagerBase
{
    public ManagerSomething1(SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        // TODO: implement logic to construct ManagerSomething1 given a data reader
    }
}

public class ManagerSomething2 : ManagerBase
{
    public ManagerSomething2(SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        // TODO: implement logic to construct ManagerSomething1 given a data reader
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create a ManagerRepository somewhere
        ManagerRepository repository = new ManagerRepository();

        // register create delegates for each type of Manager
        repository.RegisterCreate<ManagerSomething1>(dr => new ManagerSomething1(dr));
        repository.RegisterCreate<ManagerSomething2>(dr => new ManagerSomething2(dr));

        // use the repository
        int managerID = 5;
        bool withUsers = false;
        ManagerBase manager = repository.GetManager(managerID, withUsers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.  After re-reading the question I realize that the OP's situation requires a more specific "Manager" type than just `ManagerBase`, so this may not be a good approach to address this particular issue.